# Inverse of a composite function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

A standard property of composite functions is that:
$$(f\circ g)^{-1}(z)=(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})(z)$$

Is it acceptable to prove this property at the level of a high school proof (not college level), by showing that the LHS of the above is equal to the RHS. For example, here is an attempt below:
Define:
$$x=g^{-1}(y),  y=f^{-1}(z) $$

From the above two we have:
$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(y)=z$$
And we can invert the above to get:
$$LHS=(f\circ g)^{-1}(z)=x$$
And we can also simplify the right hand side:
$$RHS=(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})(z)=g^{-1}(y)=x$$
Hence,
$$LHS=RHS\implies Proved$$

I know the standard proof where I show that:
$$(f\circ g) \circ(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})=\text{Identity Function}$$
$$(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ(f\circ g) =\text{Identity Function}$$

I am NOT looking for the standard proof.

Comment: At this level you need to argue more precisely why $(f \circ g)^{-1}(z) = x$.

Comment: What you call the "standard proof" has the advantage that this property generalizes much further where one cannot explicitly work with elements. (See category theory. Though, I guess strictly speaking one could turn the elements approach into a generalized elements approach via the Yoneda Lemma...)

Comment: Can you explain what is lacking in the current proof, and whether it can be salvaged. Or should I simply revert to the standard proof (mentioned in one of the answers below), and which I do understand. Just that I would like to understand what is wrong with what I have thought.

Comment: I am fine if my approach does not generalize. I would still like to know if it is valid, or not.

Comment: I'm just saying that you still need to prove $(f \circ g)^{-1}(z) = x$ which you use. And the second comment is just a remark.

Comment: Understood your comment. I have changed  the proof, and made an attempt at showing that $$LHS=(f\circ g)^{-1}(z)=x$$. Is it sufficient?

Comment: This part is ok now. :) Overall, it is still not quite clean though. You need to be more precise with the logic of this proof. You want to show the equality for all $z$, and then given any $z$, you define $y = f^{-1}(z)$, etc. If you wish, you should also still write out $(g^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(z) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(z)) = \dots$ to make the rhs more precise.

Comment: The second part, is simple laziness. I would have written it out, but simply skipped that step.

Comment: You shouldn't be lazy at this point of your studies, especially not when writing down mathematics. At this point, it is difficult to discern where you are lazy and where you are imprecise because you didn't know you need to be more precise - so you should just always write out everything as precisely as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I shall just write out a clean proof by elements instead of writing a paramount number of comments.

**Lemma.** Let $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$ be invertible functions between sets. Then, $(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$.

*Proof.* Let $y \in Y$. Then, we write $x = f^{-1}(y)$ and $w = g^{-1}(x)$. In particular, we have $(f \circ g)(w) = f(g(w)) = f(x) = y$ which implies $w = (f \circ g)^{-1}(y)$. Thus, $$ (f \circ g)^{-1}(y) = w = g^{-1}(x) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(y)) = (g^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(y).$$ Since $y$ was chosen arbitrary, this implies the desired. $\square$

Let me follow with some remarks but these will probably still be a bit too much for you. A good time to come back to this could be when you enter graduate school (or perhaps even earlier). But maybe other readers will appreciate it, so I will leave it here.

But if you scrutinize the proof long enough, this is no more than what you call the "standard proof", only plastering the steps with a lot of element chasing. And as remarked in the comments, your "standard proof" is preferred since it generalizes far more than this proof, namely to all categories. As an example $(gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1}$ in groups follows readily from this.

And for the even greater experts, the proof by elements actually also generalizes to the categorical setting by introducing generalized elements. Then, one lands in the viewpoint of the Yoneda Lemma where elements are no more than morphisms.

Comment: Thanks. This was very useful. It is not my intention to state that my method is better. Quite the contrary. But knowing that it is correct (if clumsy) ensures I don't have the wrong concepts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Of course yes. You are simply using the associative property of the composition of functions:
$$
(f\circ g)\circ (g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}) = f\circ (g\circ g^{-1})\circ f^{-1} = f\circ \text{Id}\circ f^{-1} = f\circ f^{-1} = \text{Id}
$$
and hence it follows
$$
(f\circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}
$$
**Edit**: one thing I thought I would add is that you may notice I did not check the other way around, i.e. I didn't check that
$$
(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ (f\circ g) = \text{Id}
$$
in fact, since the set of invertible functions along with the composition forms a group, it's not needed to check the other way around. Technically, we only need to check one way round, although some professors will prefer you to still check both, so make sure you check with your prof.

Comment: @Starlight how do you mean by "without going through the steps you did"?

Comment: Have updated the question to show an attempt at a proof.